# Angular UI Router, Menu loses functionality on $state change

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

[image]

I have a nested view for my menu, which is a directive that adds classes & functionality to it, namely collapse/suppress. The items in the menu can change to a different collection should one of those links have that functionality. My problem occurs after the menu is repopulated as it loses the collapse/expand as well as click functionality. I am sure it is a matter to be handled in the $changeState event in my LayoutCtrl but I haven't found a way to re-instate the functionality from the directive:

Any help on how to re-instate the collapse and click events on a menu re-population would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thru a $watch event:

```
 <ul data-anu-menu="" menu-items="layout.menuItems">


        scope:{
            menuItems: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('menuItems', function (val1, val2) {
                if (val1.length != val2.length) {
                   $timeout(processMenu, 0);
            }});
```